# Xposed hook not working

Tags: android, xposed

I have some problems using the exposed framework, i don't understand why my logs aren't working in the beforehookedmethod and afterhookedmethod?

```
package com.example.stefan.testxposed;



import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.View;

import de.robv.android.xposed.IXposedHookLoadPackage;
import de.robv.android.xposed.IXposedHookZygoteInit;
import de.robv.android.xposed.XC_MethodHook;
import de.robv.android.xposed.XSharedPreferences;
import de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge;
import de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers;
import de.robv.android.xposed.XC_MethodHook.MethodHookParam;
import de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_LoadPackage.LoadPackageParam;

public class Tutorial implements IXposedHookZygoteInit,     IXposedHookLoadPackage  {

public static final boolean verbose = true;

// What to hook
private static final String PACKAGE_SETTINGS =
        "com.android.settings";

private static final String CLASS_SIM =
        //"com.android.settings.sim.SimDialogActivity";
"com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings";

private static XSharedPreferences mPreferences;

@Override
public void initZygote(StartupParam param) throws Throwable {
    verboseLog(this, "initZygote(StartupParam)", "Simding starting...");

    //mPreferences = new XSharedPreferences(WiFiKeyView.class.getPackage().getName());
    //mPreferences.makeWorldReadable();
}
public void handleLoadPackage(final LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
    if (!lpparam.packageName.equals(PACKAGE_SETTINGS)) return;
    verboseLog(this, "handleLoadPackage(LoadPackageParam)", "Gevonden starting...");

    final Class<?> SettingsClazz = XposedHelpers.findClass(CLASS_SIM, lpparam.classLoader);
    XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(CLASS_SIM, lpparam.classLoader,"onCreateContextMenu", ContextMenu.class, View.class, ContextMenuInfo.class, new XC_MethodHook() {

        @Override
        protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
            verboseLog(this, "beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam)", "In de hook...");
            //Tutorial.verboseLog(this, "beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam)", "ding.");
        }
        @Override
        protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
            XposedBridge.log("AFTER");
            verboseLog(this, "beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam)", "In de hoook...");
            //Tutorial.verboseLog(this, "afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam)", "ding.");
        }
    });
}

public static void verboseLog(Object who, String methodAndParams, String what) {
    if (verbose) {
        String packageAndClass = (who instanceof Class) ? ((Class<?>) who).getCanonicalName() : who.getClass().getCanonicalName();
        String tag = "SimSettings (" + packageAndClass + "#" + methodAndParams + ")";

        Log.v(tag, what);
        XposedBridge.log(tag + " " + what);
    }
}
}
```

And my log file is as follows:

06-12 11:42:50.319 I/Xposed  (  359):   Loading class com.example.stefan.testxposed.Tutorial
06-12 11:42:50.335 I/Xposed  (  359): SimSettings (com.example.stefan.testxposed.Tutorial#initZygote(StartupParam)) Simding starting...
06-12 11:43:09.689 I/Xposed  ( 5717): SimSettings (com.example.stefan.testxposed.Tutorial#handleLoadPackage(LoadPackageParam)) Gevonden starting...
06-12 11:43:11.010 I/Xposed  ( 5993): SimSettings (com.example.stefan.testxposed.Tutorial#handleLoadPackage(LoadPackageParam)) Gevonden starting...
06-12 11:43:13.133 I/Xposed  ( 6385): SimSettings (com.example.stefan.testxposed.Tutorial#handleLoadPackage(LoadPackageParam)) Gevonden starting...
06-12 11:43:14.124 I/Xposed  ( 6528): SimSettings (com.example.stefan.testxposed.Tutorial#handleLoadPackage(LoadPackageParam)) Gevonden starting...
06-12 11:43:15.077 I/Xposed  ( 6670): SimSettings (com.example.stefan.testxposed.Tutorial#handleLoadPackage(LoadPackageParam)) Gevonden starting...
06-12 11:43:16.500 I/Xposed  ( 6880): SimSettings (com.example.stefan.testxposed.Tutorial#handleLoadPackage(LoadPackageParam)) Gevonden starting...
06-12 11:43:48.390 I/Xposed  ( 8719): SimSettings (com.example.stefan.testxposed.Tutorial#handleLoadPackage(LoadPackageParam)) Gevonden starting...
06-12 11:44:51.582 I/Xposed  ( 9083): SimSettings (com.example.stefan.testxposed.Tutorial#handleLoadPackage(LoadPackageParam)) Gevonden starting...
06-12 11:44:52.545 I/Xposed  ( 9248): SimSettings (com.example.stefan.testxposed.Tutorial#handleLoadPackage(LoadPackageParam)) Gevonden starting...
06-12 11:44:53.608 I/Xposed  ( 9415): SimSettings (com.example.stefan.testxposed.Tutorial#handleLoadPackage(LoadPackageParam)) Gevonden starting...
06-12 11:44:55.309 I/Xposed  ( 9725): SimSettings (com.example.stefan.testxposed.Tutorial#handleLoadPackage(LoadPackageParam)) Gevonden starting...
06-12 11:45:31.457 I/Xposed  (10704): SimSettings (com.example.stefan.testxposed.Tutorial#handleLoadPackage(LoadPackageParam)) Gevonden starting...

In this log file i dont see these two lines back?:
verboseLog(this, "beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam)", "In de hook...");
verboseLog(this, "beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam)", "In de hoook...");

Comment: Either there was an exception or the methods didnt run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was something stupid, it already worked.. but i didn't trigger the WifiSettings onCreateContextMenu method. After the trigger it worked! I assumed xposed did trigger the function but it would not. So it was my own mistake